# using fork twice - weird behavior

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'm trying to create 2 child processes and connect them with pipe, but somethings goes wrong with my code.

```
int des_p[2];
if(pipe(des_p) == -1) {
    perror("Pipe failed");
    exit(1);
}
if((this->procId = fork())==0){ //filter for only the SON process to pass
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);   //closing stdout
    dup(des_p[1]);      //replacing stdout with pipe write 
    close(des_p[0]);    //closing pipe read
    close(des_p[1]);    //closing pipe write

    execvp(op1, argsp1);
    perror("execvp failed");
    exit(1);
}
if(this->procIdSecondary = fork() == 0)            //creating 2nd child, also a filter for only the SON process to pass
{
    close(STDIN_FILENO);    //closing stdin
    dup(des_p[0]);      //replacing stdin with pipe read
    close(des_p[1]);    //closing pipe write
    close(des_p[0]);    //closing pipe read

    execvp(op2, argsp2);
    perror("execvp failed");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
        cout <<"pid=" << this->procIdSecondary<<endl;

}

close(des_p[0]); 
close(des_p[1]);
```

`

I get pid=0

how is that possible ?

Comment: Operator precedence. Add parentheses around the assignments in the if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is operator precedence in this `if` statement

```
if(this->procIdSecondary = fork() == 0)
```

`this->procIdSecondary` gets assigned the result of the comparison. Add parenthesis as in the first `if`.